# Forwarding IPv6 traffic

Tags: linux, networking, centos, ipv6

How can I forward IPv6 traffic from my tun0 interface to the eth0 interface?

ifconfig:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:16:3E:12:77:54  
          inet addr:208.111.39.160  Bcast:208.111.39.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: 2607:f740:0:3f::eda/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::216:3eff:fe12:7754/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:65590 errors:0 dropped:499 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:40111 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:13246038 (12.6 MiB)  TX bytes:28807669 (27.4 MiB)
          Interrupt:29 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)

tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          inet addr:10.8.0.1  P-t-P:10.8.0.2  Mask:255.255.255.255
          inet6 addr: 2607:f740:44:22::8/64 Scope:Global
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:16876 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:16504 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:100 
          RX bytes:2235766 (2.1 MiB)  TX bytes:7680377 (7.3 MiB)
```

I have forwarding enabled:

```
[root@baobei ~]# sysctl net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding
net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding = 1
```

Firewall:

```
ip6tables -F INPUT
ip6tables -F FORWARD
ip6tables -F OUTPUT
ip6tables -F 

ip6tables -P INPUT ACCEPT
ip6tables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
ip6tables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT

echo -n "1" >/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/forwarding
echo -n "1" >/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/proxy_ndp
echo -n "0" >/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/autoconf
echo -n "0" >/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/accept_ra
ip6tables -A INPUT -p icmpv6 -j ACCEPT
ip6tables -A FORWARD -m state --state NEW -i tun0 -o eth0 -s 2607:f740:44:22::/64 -j ACCEPT
ip6tables -A FORWARD -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

Routes:

```
unreachable ::/96 dev lo  metric 1024  error -101
unreachable ::ffff:0.0.0.0/96 dev lo  metric 1024  error -101
unreachable 2002:a00::/24 dev lo  metric 1024  error -101
unreachable 2002:7f00::/24 dev lo  metric 1024  error -101
unreachable 2002:a9fe::/32 dev lo  metric 1024  error -101
unreachable 2002:ac10::/28 dev lo  metric 1024  error -101
unreachable 2002:c0a8::/32 dev lo  metric 1024  error -101
unreachable 2002:e000::/19 dev lo  metric 1024  error -101
2607:f740:0:3f::/64 dev eth0  proto kernel  metric 256 
2607:f740:44:22::/64 dev tun0  proto kernel  metric 256 
unreachable 3ffe:ffff::/32 dev lo  metric 1024  error -101
fe80::/64 dev eth0  proto kernel  metric 256 
fe80::/64 dev tun0  proto kernel  metric 256 
default via 2607:f740:0:3f::1 dev eth0  metric 1
```

However ipv6 packets which arrive at the tun0 interface are not routed to the eth0 interface. Thanks for any help, suggestions.

Comment: Do you have routes that would make sense here?  What is your route table look like?  `ip -6 route show`

Comment: It's not really a duplicate, no mention of OpenVPN and this is a very specific question, the other very general.

Comment: added route show to main question

Comment: It's exactly the same issue; you should have updated your existing question rather than start a new one.

Comment: If you successively get it shut down i'll have to. But as I said this is a narrow question, I would have to delete all the configs and logs from the other question which would make it not make sense to those who already replied.

Comment: This is exactly the detail that you should have provided originally. So go right ahead.

Comment: @user66779, If this is the same issue, you could also close other question, and just make it go away.

Comment: I'll close the other, one of the comments in that question solved a major problem, which just leaves the one in this question, lol.

Comment: Old question closed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a simple question of routing.  Your routing table, doesn't have any routes to direct traffic over the tun0 interface, so nothing gets forwarded that way.

I gather you are using OpenVPN.  As far as I know right now, the IPv6 support for OpenVPN doesn't include an IPv6 equivalent of the `redirect-gateway` option.  You probably need to add your own routes with `route-ipv6` statements pushed from the server.

Comment: According to the manual, --route-ipv6 ipv6addr/bits [gateway] [metric], so i'm guessing route-ipv6 2607:f740:44:22::/64 eth0 1

Comment: @user66779, no, that is not how you route.  Check your route table, a route for `2607:f740:44:22::/64` already exists.   What you probably need is a **default route**, or something like what the `def1` option to the ipv4 redirect gateway does for you, by sending a few routes.

Comment: Like this?: ip -6 route add <ipv6network>/<prefixlength> via <ipv6address> dev <device>]

Comment: Also found: route -A inet6 add <ipv6network>/<prefixlength> gw <ipv6address> [dev <device>]

Comment: both of those are commands that add routes, but you are missing the point, the `route-ipv6` openvpn option to set a route is perfectly fine, what you need to figure out is **the correct route(s)** to add.

Comment: adding this fixed it: push "route-ipv6 2607:f740:44:22::/64"
push "route-ipv6 2000::/3" but i have no idea why. What does 2000::/3 mean?

Comment: Well for starters, the '::' means this is a sequence of zeros. /3 means netmask for the route. 2000 is a routing prefix. See simipledns.com/private-ipv6.aspx for your own ipv6 routing prefix.